# Display on multiple selections

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I want to know how can I display both `div`s on selected both option in select box. I want to display if `Квартира` and `Гараж` are selected to display their respective divs.

[here's code](http://jsfiddle.net/3nq95/)

```
<select id="multiple" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Гараж</option>
  <option>Загородный дом</option>
  <option>Квартира</option>
</select>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge required" name="project_title" id="project_title" value="" />

<div class="panel" id="foo123" ><h3 class="pane-toggler title" id="panel_id114"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Квартира</span></a></h3><div class="pane-slider content"><div class="row-fluid" style="padding: 0 15px;"><div class="span12"><div class="test"><div class="span4"><label for="id_category_112" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="id_category[]" id="id_category_112" value="112" class="jb-checkboxes parent-checkbox" data-id="112">- Стройка</label><ul class="child"><li class="child-113">
                            <input type="checkbox" data-parent="112" class="ch parent-id-112" data-price="{&quot;first&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;second&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;third&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}" name="id_category[]" value="113">
                            <b>- Фундамент</b>
                            <input type="text" name="cat_val[113]" placeholder="м2." data-cat="113" class="type-cat type-113" value="">
                        </li></ul></div></div>
</div></div></div></div>


<div class="panel" id="foo1234" ><h3 class="pane-toggler title" id="panel_id114"><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Гараж</span></a></h3><div class="pane-slider content"><div class="row-fluid" style="padding: 0 15px;"><div class="span12"><div class="test"><div class="span4"><label for="id_category_112" class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="id_category[]" id="id_category_112" value="112" class="jb-checkboxes parent-checkbox" data-id="112">- Стройка</label><ul class="child"><li class="child-113">
                            <input type="checkbox" data-parent="112" class="ch parent-id-112" data-price="{&quot;first&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;second&quot;:&quot;2&quot;,&quot;third&quot;:&quot;3&quot;}" name="id_category[]" value="113">
                            <b>- Фундамент</b>
                            <input type="text" name="cat_val[113]" placeholder="м2." data-cat="113" class="type-cat type-113" value="">
                        </li></ul></div></div>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ".val()" method is returning a comma separated list of the selected values. You can use the ":selected" css selector to check which items are selected and perform the desired actions.

Here's a snippet from your code that is modified to work:

```
$("#multiple").change(function(){
    $("#foo123").hide();
    $("#foo1234").hide();
    $('#multiple :selected').each(function(i, selected) {
        var val = $(selected).val();
        if(val === 'Квартира') {
            $("#foo123").show();           
        }
        if(val === 'Гараж') {
            $("#foo1234").show();
        }
    });      
});
```